# Angular wait for service function Ajax completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get from my controller the result of an $http request.

Here is my service :

```
.service('postService', function($http, apiUrl) {

    return {
        post: function(uri, params) {
            $http.post(apiUrl + uri, params).then(function(items) {                 
                    return items.data;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

And here what I've done in my controller :

```
var getData = postService.post('my_service_url', {id: 'test'});
getData.then(function(result) {
       $scope.data = result;
       console.log(data);
});
```

But I catch the error :

> getData is undefined

What is the way to achieve this ?

Comment: You don't return anything from your post method (missed 'return' statement), so result is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* the `$http.post`

```
return {
    post: function(uri, params) {
        return $http.post(apiUrl + uri, params);
    }
};
```

Then you can hook up your `then`:

```
var getData = postService.post('my_service_url', {id: 'test'});
getData.then(function(result) {
       $scope.data = result;
       console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the $q module of angularjs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Your service code could look like this:

```
.service('postService', function($http, $q, apiUrl) {

    return {
        post: function(uri, params) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post(apiUrl + uri, params).then(function(items) {                 
                    deferred.resolve(items.data);
            }, function() {
              // error case
                    deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: `http.post` [returns a Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), there is no need (and in fact its an anti-pattern) to define and return your own promise